# Entity Framework code-first: understanding entity relations (one-to-many)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm fairly new to Entity Framework and just encountered a problem I don't understand.

Here is what I have done: I created a class `Event`:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

and a class `Address`:

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StreeName { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

And the contexts accordingly

```
public class EventContext : DbContext
{
    public EventContext(DbContextOptions<EventContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Event> Event { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class AddressContext : DbContext
{
    public AddressContext(DbContextOptions<AddressContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

So there is no problem here. But when I update my database with

```
Update-Database -Context EventContext
```

and

```
Update-Database -Context AddressContext
```

My database looks like that:

[image: Database Schema]

What I don't understand here is, why does EF creates 2 tables for `Event` (`Event` and `Events`) and `Address` (`Address` and `Addresses`)?

My goal is that the `Event` has just one related `Address`.

Comment: Why do you want to have two DbContexts?

Comment: Try to use just **ONE** `MyEntitiesContext` that contains both the `DbSet<Event>` and the `DbSet<Address>`

Comment: You mean for Event and Address? Well i want to fetch and edit addresses aswell as all other entities, thats why i created two DbContexts. But maybe i am wrong here?

I will try it out!

Comment: as marc_s said, try using just on dbcontext.

Comment: You should use one `DbContext` per *model*, not per *table*.  Your current code sets up 2 different models with distinct table sets.

Comment: Thank you guys. That worked, was a big misunderstanding on my side. Thanks for clearing that out

Comment: When you are new to EF but have experience with database layouts you can create your database the old way and then create your model from an existing structure. This helps to understand what EF needs for a given structure.